# Mock location that is find from the app

Tags: gps-tracking

I usually used a Fake GPS APP in order to smart-work from different location and not only from my home.

Now the APP that I use in order to login to my work, I don't know how,
but it understand that I use a Fake GPS APP, so I can't use it anymore.
Is there possibility to solve this problem please ?

Thanks all in advance
Denis

Comment: Any app can find out that the location [`isMock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#isMock()). You need a framework mod like Xposed to hide this from apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer... I'll study this Xposed in order to understand more and then I'll ask some other help. Thanks again.